# What is equivalent of "persona non grata" for a company?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

If I wanted to use an equivalent of `persona non grata` to describe a company with which I would not want to do business, what's the best translation of "company", i.e. in the financial/commercial sense?

I'm thinking `corpus non gratum`, in the sense of a company as a single body (from which we get "corporation") but is there a better word/translation? Google translate (yes, yes; I know) is offering `turba` which seems like the wrong sense, i.e. more like a loose mob of people acting together.

Comment: Since that latest debacle, Key bank officers have been personae non gratae at headquarters. -or- Due to what we perceive as a fundamental lack of reliability and responsibility your agents should consider themselves personae non gratae effective immediately. It's really the maneuvering in the English sentence structure that can reduce the issue to simple pluralization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is mainly about finding a good Latin expression for a company.
Pitkäranta's dictionary suggests *opus mercatorium* or *societas mercatoria*.
These feel a bit too heavy for the intended use, and without the adjectives the nouns [*opus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DO%3Aentry+group%3D27%3Aentry%3Dopus1) and [*societas*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=societas&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) are too broad to be understood as "company".
Of these two *societas* is better as a standalone translation, but it still doesn't quite work.

The word [*corpus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=corpus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) you suggest is a possibility, but is suffers from similar broadness.
It might work well with an added adjective (like *mercatorium*), but then the phrase becomes too long to my taste.

As you mention, [*turba*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=turba&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is closer to "mob" or "confusion" than "company".
Unless mockery is intended, I suggest choosing another word.

Instead, I propose using the word *firma*, which can be seen as the Latin version of the English "[firm](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/firm)".
It can be used to refer to a company of some kind in Latin (also according to the aforementioned dictionary) and most importantly, the word is correctly understood by many people with no education in Latin.
Replacing *persona* with *firma* should be clear enough for most.
They are also both conveniently feminines, so the adjective *grata* can stay as it is.

I therefore suggest ***firma non grata***.

Comment: I'm not very easy about using _firma_. I'd much prefer _negotium_ (_negotium non gratum_), which I think would indicate directly that [I] didn't want to do business.